# Does a dual-core ARM7 provide cache coherency between the cores?

Tags: ios, arm

On Intel processors, each core has its own L1 an L2 caches. Is this true on the ARM dual-core processors? If so, can I rely on cache coherency between the two cores, such that a thread running on core 0 will always see the same data in its cache that core 1 see in its?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ARM processors starting with Cortex-A9 series provides cache coherency through hardware snooping.

As a developer, much easier to do multicore :).

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407e/CDDEHDDG.html

Comment: Actually, starting with ARM11 MPcore, which is an implementation of ARMv6k ISA.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean ARMv7?  I dont think there is an ARM7 dual core, you could put two in a chip sure but they would be independent (and they didnt come with caches so you would have to implement your own).

Here is the story with ARM, not really any different than intel except intel is in the chip business, arm is in the IP business they dont make chips.

start at http://infocenter.arm.com create a free account some of the docs, ARMv7 in particular you are going to need to log in.

There are two types of ARM docs.  There are the ARM ARM's the ARM Architectural Reference Manual's.  Used to be one big manual covering all the cores, now it is broken into core families covering the overall similarities, instruction set, etc for a family of cores.  Since you are asking about dual/multi core you are likely talking about the Cortex-A ARMv7-A (not the ARMv7-M those are single core microcontrollers).  Or maybe you meant the ARMv6 cores like the mpcore which has a one to four core variant.  On the infocenter site along the left under contents you select arm architecture then the first thing is reference manuals.  This is like the general practitioner of arm docs, the family doctor, not a specialist in any field just knows something about everything.

The second type of arm doc is the TRM, the technical reference manual, this is the specialist, the brain surgeon or podiatrist, etc.  You find the specific core that the chip vendor is using (can be easy or hard depending on the chip and vendor) and that will describe what the edges of the core look like it will describe where the caches are, who shares them or not and how.  Note that the L1 cache and mmu are often in the TRM for the core, the L2 cache is an extra cost item, not necessarily purchased by the chip vendor.  the L1 cache, nor mmu, does not necessarily sit on the amba, axi bus, the l2 is an amba/axi in, amba/axi out shim, modifying or consuming transactions as they go by, you still have to put your memory system on the outer layer amba/axi.

The short answer is you need to be more specific about which arm core you are talking about, and then once you know that find the TRM for that core, and it will include the answer to your question.