# dual-cores x86 can handle byte-level concurrent accesses (?) who else?

Tags: c, linux, caching, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I wrote the following code to be executed in parallel by several processes:

```
// spawn 10 times with id=0..9 by a master process.
void slave_processing(int id)
{
  SHARED_TYPE last=id;
   for(;;) {
     /* each slave operates on a specific byte of the shared array. */
     if (shared[id]!=last) fprintf(stderr,"S%i expected %i\n",id,last);
     shared[id]+=id;
     last+=id;
     if (last>10*id) {last=0; shared[id]=0;}
   }
}
```

They're all using the same (IPC/linux) shared memory, but each accessing a separate entry of the array. It works flawlessly on my dual-core machine both when `SHARED_TYPE` is `int` and `char`. I compiled with aggressive optimisation (-O3) and checked the assembled binary to confirm memory references are performed for `shared[id]` accesses and a register is used for `last`.

Yet, I'm puzzled. I'd have expected that at some point, affecting bytes from one core may not have reflected on the cached content from the other core. E.g. one core might have [xxyyzzuu] in cache and write back [xxyyZZuu] to memory while in the same time another core had upgraded the memory word to [XXyyzzuu] (assuming each pair of char is a byte in my 32-bit word).

Is linux doing some magic setup so that memory obtained with `shmget` cannot be cached ? or is there some low-level cache syncrhonisation going on that ensure core #1 can read the latest modification of core #2 to update the selected byte without nasty side-effects ?

Is there any other (multi-core) architecture you know where the above code would have failed (entered fprintf) ?

Comment: Looks like according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8813425/15304, the key feature I'm interested in is cache coherency through hardware snooping ...

Comment: I don't see how with this code you are expecting to see mismatch of the data. You are only printing `id` and that one isn't changed in your code. You'd have to print out `shared[id]` no?

Comment: `shared[id]` is read and printed by the master process, but the checking is actually in the `shared[i]!=last`. I've edited the question to make my expectation clearer.

Comment: Most modern systems enforce cache coherency at the hardware level, so that this will work the way you observe, without undue requirements on the OS or application to address coherency issues. So you should never observe issues with the consistency of the data. What you might see, however, in a scenario like this, if you use the same cache lines repeatedly on multiple cores/chips, is a performance drop compared to, e.g. allocating a separate cache line for each thread to use.

Comment: @sylvainulg, and that's your answer - caches with no cache coherency - fail. No cache or cache with cache coherency - success.

Comment: Oh, boy... no it cannot.

Comment: @chill, too many caches with cache coherence is also fail (from scalability point of view). That's why the future of HPC looks more and more non-cache coherent.

Comment: @HristoIliev, perhaps, although I consider the critical point to be non-sharing of data (for writes) rather than cache architecture.

Comment: @chill, sorry, my statement turned out ambiguous. It was about the number of cores/CPUs and keeping large (NUMA) systems cache coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code assumes the compiler does not cache(e.g. read the content from memory once into a register and continues to use the register instead of memory) any of the values it meddles with in your loop, but does a memory fetch for each read from the shared segment. To ensure all parts see data written to memory, accessing the `shared` array should be done with memory barriers.

Though compiler dependent , it will normally do a memory fetch if your `shared` is volatile.

Since you call fprintf(), the compiler must assume fprintf() could access or update something in the `shared` array - after all, the compiler doesn't know what fprintf() does, so theoretically it could access a global array, the compiler is required to re-fetch that memory from `shared`(unless it can otherwise prove it's impossible for fprintf update it)

Your code might behave differently if `shared` is not volatile ,and you e.g. do

```
SHARED_TYPE last=id;
int wrong = 0,i;
for(i = 0; i < 10000000;i++) {
  if (shared[id]!=last) wrong++;
  shared[id]+=id;
  last+=id;
  if (last>10*id) {last=0; shared[id]=0;}
}
return wrong;
```

The compiler is not required to do a memory fetch to get the latest value of `shared[id]` on each iteration here. Then again, if the compiler does cache a value, it might just spin the loop, checking the same right thing again and again without getting updated values from memory, leaving `wrong` = 0 as expected. Whatever you do here is not safe, and depends what code the compiler would generate for you - it might generate code with substantial different results for small code changes.

Intertwined with this is what data types can be atomically read from memory, which will depend on the processor, the data type and whether the access is memory aligned.

This is in addition to cache-coherence. The common desktop and server platforms we use are cache-coherent, which means the hardware takes care of the magic of updating memory so changes are seen by all processors/cores and not e.g. residing in a L1 cache on only 1 core when another core needs to access the same memory location. (Some memory regions e.g. regions used for DMA might not give you such cache coherence guarantees)

Desktop/server platforms today are looking quite NUMA like, but many bigger and more special built NUMA systems not have a cache-coherence guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explorations of the possibilities. setting the array `volatile` didn't changed the outcome of the test.

Comment: Well, if anything, making it volatile would give you greater chance of success, if you already got lucky with the code the compiler generated, it'd not improve it more, or less.